# ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odac

I am using Oracle Data Access from .net and my query is as

```
command.CommandText = "select * from table1 where expirydate =:EXPIRYDATE";
command.Parameters.Add("EXPIRYDATE", OracleDbType.Date, DateTime.Today,ParameterDirection.Input);

var results = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

I get the following error " ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER"

If I change my query to:

```
command.CommandText ="select * from table1 where expirydate =
to_date(:EXPIRYDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY')";
```

I get no results.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

Most likely reason for this error is that the order of the parameters in your query does not match the order you add them to the `Parameters` collection. Oracle Data Access pretends to bind them by name, but actually binds them by order.

Comment: Not true. read the documentation. Set Command property BindByName  specifies wether bind by name or order

Answer (score 9):

If you're using ODP.NET, OracleCommand should have a BindByName property which will force the command to bind parameters by their name instead of their order.

```
const string sql = @"select :parameter2, :parameter1 from dual";

using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":parameter1", "FOO"))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":parameter2", "BAR"))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    reader.Read();
    // should print "FOOBAR"
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1));
}

using (var cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn) { BindByName = true })
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":parameter1", "FOO"))
using (cmd.Parameters.Add(":parameter2", "BAR"))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    reader.Read();
    // should print "BARFOO"
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", reader.GetValue(0), reader.GetValue(1));
}
```

There is a slight performance penalty associated with this, but it's probably small enough to be negligible in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you add parameters by name, if you don't explicitly tell OracleCommand that you are using bind by name, it uses bind by order / index. I got the same error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER", when i set BindByName to true, it worked.

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand()
{
    Connection = conn,
    BindByName = true
};
```